# How to use a Query or QueryTask on local graphics ? (GraphicsLayer)

Tags: angular, typescript, arcgis-js-api

I'm working on a prototype of ESRI map with Angular4. I have successfully been using the `Draw` tool to `Query` on a `FeatureLayer` some points to draw graphics like `ConvexHull` and `Buffer`.

My main objective was to realize a clean `Buffer` graphic over a `ConvexHull` graphic (*I will call this `BufferOfPoints`*).
Now, I'm interested in realizing a `Buffer` graphic of a **combination** of 2 or more of the previous `Buffers`.

The issue is that for the `BufferOfPoints`, I could realize a `Query` with the Drawing tools on the `FeatureLayer` which contained my points. 
My objective is now to `Query` the same way the Buffer graphics, but those are not in a `FeatureLayer` but in a `GraphicsLayer`, which is not "Queryable".

I find it really weird to not be able to do something as simple as that...
Is there a simple solution to do that ?

---

Here is my code for the working simple case, and the one I'm stuck on...

**Working case (simplified)**

```
    // Get the Toolbar instance
    this.drawToolbar.on('draw-complete', (RectangularSelectorGeometry) => {
      this.drawToolbar.deactivate();

      // Initialize the Query
      const query = new Query();
      query.geometry = RectangularSelectorGeometry.geometry;

      // Manage the actions for each configured layer
      featureLayersConcerned.forEach(featureLayer => {
        featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, (features) => {
          // Get the selected graphic points
          const points = features.map((feature) => {
            return feature.geometry;
          });

          ...

          // Calculate the convex Hull geometry
          // Create the BufferParameters
          // Apply the buffer on the ConvexHullResult
          // Show the buffer result
        });
      });
    });
```

**Not Working case (simplified)**

```
    // Get the Toolbar instance
    this.drawToolbar2.on('draw-complete', (RectangularSelectorGeometry) => {
      this.drawToolbar2.deactivate();

      // Initialize the Query
      const query = new Query();
      query.geometry = RectangularSelectorGeometry.geometry;

      // Get the Graphic layer if it exists or create it otherwise
      let graphicLayer = this.map.getLayer('bufferGraphics');
      if (!graphicLayer) {
        graphicLayer = new GraphicsLayer({ id: 'bufferGraphics' });
        this.map.addLayer(graphicLayer);
      }

      graphicLayer.selectFeatures(query, GraphicsLayer.SELECTION_NEW, (features) => {  // <== Doesn't work :/

       ...

       // Calculate the convex Hull geometry
       // Create the BufferParameters
       // Apply the buffer on the ConvexHullResult
       // Show the buffer result
      });
    });
```

---

Here is a link to help you understand : https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=exp_cors_buffer

In this link, select a simple graphic and buffer it. This is exactly the `BufferOfPoints` I was talking about. My new objective is to query 2 of those red areas and draw a new Buffer with them.

Hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer is correct in that geometries do not manage a `SelectionSet` like `featureLayers` do.  However...

Although it is not strictly a `query` function operating on graphics, you can  perform a`graphicsUtils.getGeometries()` on the buffered result graphics will at least get you an array of geometry objects.  If you can determine which of the geometries you are interested in, you can then instance features and buffer the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

The graphicslayer does not have a selectFeatures() method.

Ref: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#methods

You can't query on graphics in a graphicslayer.  Only on features in a featurelayer.  The reason, and main different between the two layers, is that for the featurelayer is a structured layer, with all the features having the same fields (and metadata about them) and of the same geometry type. For a graphicslayer there is no such metadata, or restriction/structure on fields/geometry for individual graphics.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you might want to look at using FeatureCollections with the FeatureLayer (instead of a graphicslayer): 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer2

Comment: The purpose is to make a prototype for a bigger project. It's just to show the feasibility to the client. So my aim is to "recreate" the old functionnalities of the first flash/flex ArcGis map, and for that purpose, I'd like to use some Graphics created from `buffer()` or `convexHull()`. And I didn't find a solution to be able to Query those graphics I just created. The only thing that comes to my mind is to add those graphics to a `FeatureLayer` but I don't need in my case to bother managing them through the `GeometryService`... I can't believe it's that hard to query those with a Draw tool..